Height above water of a floating sphere
I have struggled to find the height $h$ above water of a sphere placed in water.

I know the weight $w$ of the sphere in grams, the diameter $d$ of the sphere in mm, and that I am using "ordinary" tap water, which has a density of $1\, g/{\rm cm}^{3}$.



I know that the displaced water's volume ( and weight ) equals the displaced object's volume ( and weight ).
But I need help finding the height above the water.
I don't know which formulas to use and where to look them up.

Thanks in advance for your help !.

The spherical cap of a ball is known to be $V=(3r-z)\frac{\pi z^2}3$, where $z$ is the segments height. From your given values $h,d,w$ you further get $z=d-h$ and $r=\frac d2$.
By the principle of Archimedes you know that this volume's weight, i.e. $m=V\cdot\varrho$, when filled with water ($\varrho\approx 1\ g/cm^3$), should equate to $w$.
--- rk

It is probably easiest to work with grams and mm throughout this question, so the numerical value of $\varrho$ is $0.001$.

I converted $d$ to cm and then added it into the formula and let wolfram alpha solve for h. But I got 3 Answers, one of them is negative. That seems a bit off, does it?

I think, with your help, I found the answer. Just for documentation purpose: In my case is $d=35.7mm=3.57cm$ and $w=2g$. When I insert that into the formula you provided: $V=(3\frac{d}{2}-(d-h))\frac{\pi (d-h)^2}{3}$, I get $2=(3\frac{3.57}{2}-(3.57-h))\frac{\pi (3.57-h)^2}{3}$ and solving for $h$ in wolfram-alpha gives me $h=-1.71667$, $h=2.93381$ and $h=4.13785$. That seems plausible, I guess.
